# JFrame whose content changes as we click on the different buttons

Tags: java, swing, jframe, cardlayout

I am using `Java's Swing` here to make a UI application. I have a created a JFrame, with some buttons. When I click on this button, I want a new JFrame with some different content at this place. However, I do not want a new JFrame to load here.

One approach, I know is of setting the visbility of the second JFrame to be True in the `actionPerformed(ActionEvent obj)` method of the button in the first JFrame. But it again loads a new JFrame and I don't want that.

```
public class FirstUI extends JFrame {
    JButton but1;

    public FirstUI(){
        but1= new JButton("Click here");
        add(but1);

    XYZ obj= new XYZ():
    but1.addActionListener(obj);
    }

    public class XYZ implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent obj1){

             // WHAT TO DO HERE  
        } 
    }
}
```

I only want a single JFrame whose content changes as we click on different buttons. How can I achieve that ?

Comment: why don't you try for JInternalFrame?

Comment: so, to clarify, you don't necessarily want a new JFrame but new content in your current JFrame to appear, when a button is clicked, right?

Comment: @Simon: Yeah.. Exactly

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html), this would allow to switch the content of your frame:

> A CardLayout object is a layout manager for a container. It treats each component in the container as a card. Only one card is visible at a time, and the container acts as a stack of cards. The first component added to a CardLayout object is the visible component when the container is first displayed.

See [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for an example.

Answer (score 3):

You can also dynamically manipulate the contents of your `JFrame` at runtime. You can use `add(...)`, `remove(...)`, `removeAll(...)` methods to add and remove the contents as you do before showing the frame. After you're done you need to call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` methods of the modified container to make everything settle down and displayed properly.

However I think the right solution depends on the actual concept you are trying to implement. If you want to add or remove a couple of GUI elements to emphasize a functionality, then the correct way is to manipulate the container as I outlined. But if you want slightly different GUI depending on system state (not more then 2-3) then `CardLayout` would be a better suited choice

Answer (score 0):

You can set visibility of parent class false.

Then you get only one Frame at a time with your required content.

You have to create static object of the frame and setVisible(fase) at the click event of the Button.

Ex.

```
public class demo  {
static JFrame jf;
public static void main(String a[])
{
    JButton b=new JButton("OK");
    JPanel jp=new JPanel();
    jf=new JFrame();
    jf.setVisible(true);
    jf.setSize(200,200);
    jf.add(jp);
    jp.add(b);

    b.addActionListener( new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
     jf.setVisible(false);
     JFrame f= new JFrame();
     f.setSize(200,200);
     f.setVisible(true);
    }
    });
}
```

}

It will help you.

you got my point?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to change the JFrame's Content Pane. which is basically a JPanel. You can do that by`frame.setContentPane( <your new panel> );`
The Second approach is to do what @Peter Lang did. and that is to use a Layout Manager which could change different content groups.